# 'Expected expression' error in macro-compound-expression in C

Tags: c, macros, expression

I tried to build a defined macro function to search an element into a tab, but the compilator return an error:

```
test2.c:27:11: error: expected expression
    ret = SEARCH(tab, targ);
          ^
```

I don't understand this error as to me the assignement statement is an expression.

This is inspired by the exemple code givne in the doc of GNU compilers: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html#Local-Labels

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_EL 10
#define TAB_SIZE = NUM_EL -1

#define SEARCH(array, target)                       \
 ({                                                 \
    __label__ found;                                \
    typeof (target) _SEARCH_target = (target);      \
    typeof (*(array)) *_SEARCH_array = (array);     \
    int i;                                          \
    int value;                                      \
    for(i = 0; i <= TAB_SIZE; i++);                 \
        if (_SEARCH_array[i] == _SEARCH_target)     \
            { value = i; goto found;}               \
    value= -1;                                      \
    found:                                          \
        value;                                      \
 })

int main() {
    int tab[NUM_EL] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int ret = 0, targ = 5;

    printf("Exemple test!\n");
    ret = SEARCH(tab, targ);
}
```

---

EDIT SOLVED:
here is the code corrected and working properly

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NUM_EL      10
#define TAB_SIZE    NUM_EL - 1

#define SEARCH(array, target)                       \
 ({                                                 \
    __label__ found;                                \
    typeof (target) _SEARCH_target = (target);      \
    typeof (*(array)) *_SEARCH_array = (array);     \
    int i;                                          \
    int value;                                      \
    for(i = 0; i <= TAB_SIZE; i++)                  \
        if (_SEARCH_array[i] == _SEARCH_target)     \
            { value = i; goto found;}               \
    value= -1;                                      \
    found:                                          \
        value;                                      \
 })

int main() {
    int tab[NUM_EL] = {10, 52, 98, 45, 12, 31, 15, 1, -74, -10};
    int targ = 52;

    printf("Exemple test!\n");

    int res = SEARCH(tab, targ);
    res != -1 ? \
    printf("tab[%d] --> %d\n", res, targ) : \
    printf("%d Not found!\n",targ);
}
```

Comment: Why are you abusing a macro when a function would be better? Also using `goto` is not a good idea.

Comment: I went through GNU compiler documentation and saw this example, I tried to reproduce a version of it to understand it better and play with it.

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Labels.html#Local-Labels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL:DR: don't try to deal with complex macros until you thoroughly understand basic C syntax.

The problem is your macro

```
#define TAB_SIZE = NUM_EL - 1
```

which makes `TAB_SIZE` expand into the token sequence `= NUM_EL -1`.  Thus, in your `SEARCH` macro, you end up with

```
for (i = 0; i <= = NUM_EL - 1; i++);
```

Note also, the `;` on the `for` makes this an empty loop (doing nothing), so your code won't do what you expect it to do.

Comment: indeed this is a silly mistake that could have been avoided if I was more focus. thank you